# C Syntax: incrementing and assigning values in the same line

Tags: c, syntax, increment

if you have two variables: int a and int b, what exactly does this do in C code?

a++ = b

Does that make a = b + 1?

Comment: `a++` is not a _modifiable lvalue_. Compiler should reject it.

Comment: I think your looking for something like this: `a = b + 1;` Your assigning `b` to `a` + `1`! (@GrzegorzSzpetkowski `Compiler should reject it` NO the compiler has to! Otherwise it's a very bad compiler :D)

Comment: Here is the full code: http://pastebin.com/73W4in9u

I didnt think it'd matter if the variable is a pointer or not but I guess it does.  Can anyone explain to me what happens in that one line?

Comment: @user3808547 either edit this question to have your real code instead of `a++ = b;` or post a new question with the real code, or post a new question "what is the difference between a++ = b and *dest++ = b". (comments should not be used for asking new questions).   This question is OK by itself because "what does a++ = b; do" is a valid question  but the thread is getting messy because you ask a new question in comments. The site format is one question per thread.

Answer (score 0):

To you question if this makes (`a = b + 1`):

```
a++ = b  //[Error] lvalue required as left operand of assignment
```

NO it does not! Your compiler should/ must give you an error!

If your looking for this operation(`a = b + 1`), then use it!

EDIT:

So if we take a look at your function:

```
int copy_block(int *src, int *dest, int len) {  //Function declaration, Return type int, 3 arguments (2x int * and 1x int)

    int result = 0;                             //variable assignment
    int val    = 0;                             //variable assignment
    while (len > 0) {                           //while loop
        val = *src;                             //variable assignment
        *src++;                                 //increment the value where the pointer is pointing 
        *dest++ = val;                          //increment adress by int size then assignment of val
        result = result ^ val;                  //Bitwise XOR
        len--;                                  //decrement variable
    }

    return result;                              //Return variable

}
```

Bitwise XOR example:

```
  X      Y     X^Y
true   false  true
true   true   false
false  false  false
false  true   true

a = 45 ^ 35;  // a == 14

45 = 0010 1101
35 = 0010 0011
---------------
14 = 0000 1110
```

Also for further reference:

[Operator priority](http://de.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence)

[Bitwise operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations_in_C)

Comment: This isn't me writing code, it's me trying to understand code provided for a homework assignment.  The actual code is here:

http://pastebin.com/73W4in9u

Comment: @user3808547 But it's the same line of code! So what do you have to know now?

Comment: What does it mean?  For example, result ^= val can be expanded to result = result ^ val.  How can *dest++ = val; be expanded so that it's easy to understand?

Comment: @user3808547 in your line your increment the adress of the pointer! since ++ has a higher priority then * and then you assgin val to the new pointer adress!

Comment: The "edit" part doesn't answer the question; "what does `*dest++` do" is a different question and should be asked and answered separately

Comment: @MattMcNabb `*dest++` increment's the adress value since ++ has a higher priority then * after that it point's to this adress!

Comment: @MattMcNabb Also read first the comment's then you would know why i append the edit to my answer!

Comment: @MattMcNabb and if you see the first comment under my answer he posted a pastbin from his code and he want's to understand this code!

Comment: @Rizier123 this site is a Q/A format, not a "help me do this and that" format ; answers must directly relate to the question